# Find all texts begin with English alphanumeric characters and end with English characters and put them inside <span> tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

There is a page that most texts of the page are in Persian language with a specific font.
There are some website and email addresses in page.Some email addresses and website contain digits.But because of the font, this digits are shown Persian and not English.
All digits in page must be Persian but digits in email and website addresses must be English.

For example I have:

```
<div>
شرکت شماره 2 در وب سایت
wwww.web2.com
info@web2.com
2web.com
2web2web.com
22344web.com
</div>
```

Something like this will solve my problem :

CSS :

```
div span{font-family:arial;direction:ltr;}
```

first HTML solution:

```
<div>
شرکت شماره 2 در وب سایت
<span>wwww.web2.com</span>
<span>info@web2.com</span>
<span>2web.com</span>
<span>2web2web.com</span>
<span>22344web.com</span>
</div>
```

second HTML solution:

```
<div>
شرکت شماره 2 در وب سایت
wwww.web<span>2</span>.com
info@web<span>2</span>.com
<span>2</span>web.com
<span>2</span>web<span>2</span>web.com
<span>22344</span>web.com
</div>
```

I want that "شرکت شماره 2 در وب سایت" looks with implemented font (B Yekan) that show "2" like "۲" but other digits show with Arial font.

There is a lot of unorganized text in the page. I need a jQuery code that make one of my solutions.
Any suggestion about this jQuery code or any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9muV/)):

```
var regex = /\d+/g,
    div = $('div'),
    newHtml = div.html().replace(regex, function(match) { 

        return '<span>'+match+'</span>'

    });

div.html(newHtml);
```

The regular expression will capture all occurrences of 1 or more digit characters.  The callback passed to the `replace` method will then wrap each matched string of digit characters in a `span` element.

Lastly, that new HTML is set as the `div` element's HTML.

Comment: What is the appropriate regex?

Comment: I need a function that gets X and replace it with <span>X</span>
while X is JUST a string starts with :
English characters
or
digit before or after an English character
and this string is between spaces or linebreaks

your suggestion will replace digits between Persian sentences too

Comment: the problem is that both English and Persian digits in web are 1234567890 but using "B Yekan" font, all digits will look Persian like ۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹۰ but their ASCI code is the same. just they looks different because of font.